# How To Use A Function To Edit String Data?

Tags: javascript, variables, editing

Note: This is an old question that used to reference a GitHub page. That page has been deleted and thus this question was updated to remove the link.

I am trying to make a system in my chatroom where if you type a certain word (password) into the chat it will edit the username to include a special mod tag. I am doing this because we don't have profile systems and it is the best solution I could come up with. However I ran into a problem, I don't know how to edit a string's data (in this case the username) to add something to it with a function. If anybody could help it would be much appreciated.

Code:

```js
if(data.message = password) {
  username.data + "Mod" 
}
```

Extra question: In the above example, would having if(data.message = password) make it so that if it contains the variable (password) it would change it, or would it just be if they typed "password" that it would change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the new value back to the variable like this:

```js
if(data.message == password) {
  username.data = username.data + "Mod";
  // or using template string
  username.data = `${username.data}Mod`;
}
```

I assumed username is an JSON object.

Answer to extra:
You need to use `==` (just the value) or `===` (strictly check the data type and value) in `if` condition. If the `data.message` is exactly the value of password then the condition is satisfied.

If you want to check if the password is a substring (the message contains value of password anywhere in the message) then you need to use [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). demo below:

```js
if(data.message.includes(password)) {
  username.data = username.data + "Mod";
  // or using template string
  username.data = `${username.data}Mod`;
}
```

If you have more doubts, you can comment below. I'll update this answer.

**Edit:**

After reading your comment, I'm adding below sample to show you how above code works:

```js
/*
Author: chankruze (chankruze@geekofia.in)
Created: Mon Jan 31 2022 12:46:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Copyright (c) geekofia 2022 and beyond
*/

const password = "qwerty1234"

const data = {
    message1: `this is my ${password}`,
    message2: password,
}


const username = {
    data: "chankruze",
}

console.log(username.data);

if (data.message1.includes(password)) {
    console.log("password found in side data");

    username.data += "mod";
}

console.log(username.data);

if (data.message2 === password) {
    console.log("exact match");

    username.data = `${username.data}mod`;
}

console.log(username.data);
```

Comment: I tried to use it and I can see what it is supposed to do, but when I enter the password (Currently just test while im making it) it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ChocolateChara It would be better if you post your entire code on github or here so I can see what's your approach. Without code it's hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: @ChocolateChara I have added a sample code to my answer above. Please review it.

Comment: Ok, ill add my code to a github repository in a sec and send it here so it helps

Comment: I created a github repository with all the chat code in it. All the files are named the exact same as the original files too, if that affects anything. You can find it in the edit I made to the question

Comment: @ChocolateChara I am looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

- Single `=` means assignment, `==` and `===` are equality comparasins (look up the difference)
- To append to the end of a string, do `+=`
- To answer your final question, `== password` means "true if `data.message` is exactly equal to the value of the variable `password`". If you want to see if the variable `password` is contained in the string, do `data.message.contains(password)`

```js
const checkForMod = (data, username) => {
  if (data.message == password) {
    username.data += "Mod";
  }
}
```

Comment: This answers the extra question, not the question itself.

Comment: @code Read my answer again, I only answered the extra question after an edit

Comment: Okay. What about executing it in a function? (Although that's a quite simple task; just wrap it in a function)